# Form Groups based on repeated elements using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i have below requirement.

need to repeat for each based on element value.
    `<foreachvalue>3</foreachvalue>`

and for 3 group xmls

```
`<source>
<foreachvalue>3</foreachvalue>
<cycle1>BMW</cycle1>
<cycle2>Merc</cycle2>
<cycle3>Ferrari</cycle3>
<cycle1color>red</cycle1color>
<cycle2color>green</cycle2color>
<cycle3color>yello</cycle3color>
<cycle1backwheelsize>10</cycle1backwheelsize>
<cycle1frontwheelsize>11</cycle1frontwheelsize>
<cycle2backwheelsize>09</cycle2backwheelsize>
<cycle2frontwheelsize>19</cycle2frontwheelsize>
<cycle3backwheelsize>39</cycle3backwheelsize>
<cycle3frontwheelsize>32</cycle3frontwheelsize>
</source>`
```

Need a xslt to form below xml

```
`<target>
<CycleData>
<cycle1>BMW</cycle1>
<cycle1color>red</cycle1color>
<cycle1backwheelsize>10</cycle1backwheelsize>
</CycleData>
<CycleData>
<cycle1>BMW</cycle1>
<cycle1color>red</cycle1color>
<cycle1frontwheelsize>11</cycle1frontwheelsize>
</CycleData>
<CycleData>
<cycle2>Merc</cycle2>
<cycle2color>green</cycle2color>
<cycle2backwheelsize>09</cycle2backwheelsize>
</CycleData>
<CycleData>
<cycle2>Merc</cycle2>
<cycle2color>green</cycle2color>
<cycle2frontwheelsize>19</cycle2frontwheelsize>
</CycleData>
<!-- Rest Cycle Data -->
</terget>`
```

please let me know, if you need more details

```
     '  <target>
        <CycleData/>
        <CycleData/>
        <CycleData>
        <cycle3>Ferrari</cycle3>
        <cycle3color>yello</cycle3color>
        <cycle3backwheelsize>39</cycle3backwheelsize>
        <cycle3frontwheelsize>32</cycle3frontwheelsize>
        </CycleData>
        </target> '
```

Comment: Seems rather simple - where are you stuck with this?

Comment: Im stuck on dynamic loop itself with 1.0 xslt

Comment: I would say aggregate every Nth element (using position() mod N), into a group - but your input does not follow the pattern you describe: the `cycleNbackwheelsize` and `cycleNfrontwheelsize` are adjacent, so it's not clear what can one count on as unchanging.

Comment: That is challenge... as we do not have a pattern frm input

Comment: If you don't have any rules one can follow (how would you do this manually?), then this is not a challenge but an impossibility.

Comment: Ha ha... may not be possible in single xslt, but can i split it into 2 xslts ??

Comment: What is the logic to repeat for each dynamically...?

Comment: You need to explain, in plain human language, what is the logic you want to implement here. I have no idea what you mean by "repeat for each dynamically" or "dynamic loop". So far I don't see anything in common between the elements being grouped except that their names all start with "cycleN". Is this the principle you want your stylesheet to apply?

Answer (score 0):

On a very long shot that this may be the ruling logic in this case, you may want to try the following stylesheet.

It will create N `<CycleData>` elements, where N is the value of the `<foreachvalue>` node.

Then it will look at the **digits only** contained in the name of each element in the source document, and if the resulting string matches N, it will copy the element into the corresponding `<CycleData>`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-num" match="*" use="translate(local-name(), translate(local-name(), '0123456789', ''), '')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <target>
        <xsl:call-template name="create-cycles">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="source/foreachvalue"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </target>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="create-cycles">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="create-cycles">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
        <CycleData>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('elem-by-num', $n)"/>
        </CycleData>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result, when applied to your example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<target>
   <CycleData>
      <cycle1>BMW</cycle1>
      <cycle1color>red</cycle1color>
      <cycle1backwheelsize>10</cycle1backwheelsize>
      <cycle1frontwheelsize>11</cycle1frontwheelsize>
   </CycleData>
   <CycleData>
      <cycle2>Merc</cycle2>
      <cycle2color>green</cycle2color>
      <cycle2backwheelsize>09</cycle2backwheelsize>
      <cycle2frontwheelsize>19</cycle2frontwheelsize>
   </CycleData>
   <CycleData>
      <cycle3>Ferrari</cycle3>
      <cycle3color>yello</cycle3color>
      <cycle3backwheelsize>39</cycle3backwheelsize>
      <cycle3frontwheelsize>32</cycle3frontwheelsize>
   </CycleData>
</target>
```

Comment: i am sorry, am i missing something here, it picks the values from the foreach element number only.. suppose i have for each value as 3, it forming cycle group only for cycle3 rest of them or empty

Comment: @Sujan I am afraid that's all I could understand (or rather guess)  from your question. I don't think you have added anything useful to explain your request.

Comment: the response xml, you have shown is the exactly what i want, but seem to be its not resulting as shown above. i see only the last element grouped together. i see the response as i have updated in the question.

Comment: @Sujan It works fine for me: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTb so check your implementation.

Comment: im trying to run the code in Oracle Service Bus Editor to transform the data, do i need to have any prerequisite to run this ?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you should post a separate question about that.